# Is the double cone a model for projective space?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry, soft-question, analytic-geometry

How I learned conic sections in high school was as intersections of planes with a double cone. This definition always seemed arbitrary and contrived to me since the double cone isn't really a "natural" object, and arguably the conic sections seem more natural than the double cone.

Recently, I have heard that all conic sections are the same in projective space (I am almost at the point of proving it in *Algebraic Geometry: A Problem Solving Approach*). I also know that projective space can be modeled as a quotient space for lines going through the origin.

[This animation on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDqmaPEjJpk) strongly suggests that the notion of lines extending from the origin in 3-space and the double cone are intimately related notions, although I am not sure how.

> **Question:** Is the double cone (from which conic sections derive the name) just how people describe projective space to high schoolers without scaring them?

Comment: I've thought better of it. Maybe there is something to say here. My first contention is that the cone is really a natural object. $x^2+y^2=z^2$ is basically the only nondegenerate quadric $Q$ in $P^2$, and we're taking the affine cone over that, in $A^3$. Taking hyperplanes not through the origin (almost) gives you one of the affine planes in $P^2$ and some affine piece of $Q$ inside that.

Comment: So to summarize: the cone is really a stand-in for the "one true conic" in $P^2$.